# Leaflet map polygon not shown on canvas when using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, html2canvas

This is what I am doing, a click on a button and drawing my page body into a canvas

```
jQuery("#print").on("click", function() {
    myCapture();
});

function myCapture() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```

That works but the map is shown without any polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by telling [leaflet to provide tiles as canvas](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#canvas) and not as an `svg`

```
jQuery("#print").on("click", function() {
    myCapture();
});

function myCapture() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}

   var map = L.map('map', {
        renderer: L.canvas()
});
```